# How to connect Postgres DB to Google Data Studio

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

I have a cloud based Postgres DB that I want to connect to Google Data Studio, both are part of the same GC project.
When I try to use the built in connector for postgres through Data Studio I receive error Error ID: ff6a9ba9. I know my DB is working because I can connect to it outside of Data Studio

I tried using the same Postgres public IP that I can connect to from my local machine but I had to whitelist that. The problem with connecting Data Studio is I don't know the IP address of that server, so I can't whitelist it. Is there a different type of connection to use within the same GCP Project (sort of how App Engine also requires the "Connection Name")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to whitelist the following IP ranges listed under the *NOTES* section of this help document for Data Studio + Postgres connections: https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7288010?hl=en

Comment: However, I need to change 1 IP in the list, from:
`142.251.74.0/23` into `142.251.74.0/24`